# Grid of button objects with row and col attributes using Tkinter. AttributeError: 'Buttons' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

Making a game like tic tac toe where the board size is adjustable. I need the button's text to change when clicked, so I'm trying to make the buttons objects with row and col attributes. First time using any GUI so I apologize if I'm going about this all wrong.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

def create_board(board_size):
    board = []
    for x in range(board_size):
        row = []
        for col in range(board_size):
            row.append("")
        board.append(row)
    return board

board_size = 12
board = create_board(board_size)

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry(str(board_size*50)+"x"+str(board_size*50))
    
class Buttons():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.buttons = {}
    def create_button(self, x, y):
        button = tk.Button(self, text = " ")
        button.grid(row = x, column = y)
        self.buttons[(x,y)] = button
    def update_button(self, x, y, letter):
        self.buttons[(x,y)].configure(text = letter)
        
app = Buttons(root)

for x in range(board_size):
    for col in range(board_size):
        app.create_button(x, col)

root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:

AttributeError: 'Buttons' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: `self` doesn't contain a reference to a `tkinter.Widget` therefore it is no surprise that it has no attribute `tk`. you could either omit the master here `button = tk.Button(text = " ")` or use a `tkinter.Widget` instance.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb now. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well, that is how I feel everyday :DD Keep learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue as your. I found problem in line 25.

Change this:

```
button = tk.Button(self, text = " ")
```

to:

```
button = tk.Button(root, text = " ")
```

Output:

[image]